# Multiple realms for Apache and Kerberos single sign-on

Tags: apache, server, single-sign-on, kerberos

I don't have any experience with Kerberos and I couldn't find any way to achieve that.

I have a Linux machine with Apache trying to authenticate using Kerberos. The issue is that there are multiple active directories on different domains. Is there any Kerberos configuration that would allow me to try them all in order?

Or is there a simpler way to implement SSO given those constraints (Linux on one side, Windows Server on the other) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "cross-realm authentication". There must be "trust relationships" created between domains. When you organize domains into forest, they're created automatically.

More about how that works:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20160607140411/https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787646(v=ws.10).aspx
- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mir/2011/06/12/accessing-resources-across-forest-and-achieve-single-sign-on-part1/